# Sum array values by attribute name

Tags: php, arrays

I want to sum count values with same code.

This is my array:

```
$data = array(
    array(
        'code' => 02,
        'count' => 8
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 03,
        'count' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 03,
        'count' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 03,
        'count' => 7
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 11,
        'count' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 11,
        'count' => 5
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 17,
        'count' => 4
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 17,
        'count' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'code' => 17,
        'count' => 8
    )
);
```

Now I tried to group the array to sum the `count` with same code, but I think I'm wrong:

```
$new_data = [];    
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    $total = 0;
    $new_data[$v['code']] = array(
        'ttl' => $v['count'] + $total,
    );
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($new_data);
echo '</pre>';
```

What is the correct code for this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `isset` will avoid **undefined offset** error:

```
$new_data = [];
foreach($data as $k => $v){
    if (!isset($new_data[$v['code']]['ttl'])){
        $new_data[$v['code']]['ttl'] = 0;
    }
    $new_data[$v['code']]['ttl'] += $v['count'];
}
print_r($new_data);
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the keys in `$new_data` to to be the unique codes, and the values to be an an array with a key of `ttl` whose value is the sum of the counts for that particular code:

```
$new_data = [];    
foreach($data as $v){
    if (!array_key_exists($v['code'], $new_data)) {
        $new_data[$v['code']]['ttl'] = $v['count'];
    } else {
        $new_data[$v['code']]['ttl'] += $v['count'];
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated my code to check if the array key exists.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want as output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ttl] => 8
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ttl] => 9
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [ttl] => 6
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [ttl] => 14
        )

)
```

If so, you can do minor modifications to your code such as this:

```
$new_data = [];
foreach ($data as $d) {
    if (isset($new_data[$d['code']]['ttl'])) {
        $new_data[$d['code']]['ttl'] += $d['count'];
    } else {
        $new_data[$d['code']]['ttl'] = $d['count'];
    }
}
```